# Get actual time from NTP, safe offset, use it in the whole program

Tags: python, offset, ntp

Is there a nice way to tell python to use a time offset in the whole program?

For example when i use the logging module the offset should be magically added to the time.

Further calls to time.time() should give me this offset as well etc.

I can't set the system time cause this is an production server which is not fully administrated by me (jeah its complicated...) and there is already an ntp client running.

The installed ntp client often fails for no good reason, so i can not trust it.

Given is this part of an monitoring script (wich is working fine):

```
import time
import ntplib

_time_offset = 0.0 # this will be filled with the correct time/seconds by ntplib

def getActualTime(pool="pool.ntp.org"):
    """ this queries the ntp for the correct time and returns the results """
    global _time_offset
    if _time_offset != 0.0:
        pass # use cached
    else: 
        _time_offset = ntplib.NTPClient().request(pool).offset
    return float(time.time()+_time_offset)

def getActualCtime():
    return time.ctime(getActualTime())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print getActualTime()
    print getActualCtime()
```

The system time + the ntp offset (this should always be the correct time):

> > > 1403182331.57
> > >
> > > Thu Jun 19 14:52:11 2014

if i would call time.time() or time.ctime() the wrong unchecked system date will be returned.

Comment: can you give an example of correct output?

Comment: sorry for the lack of clarity. My functions working well. Im looking for a way to always add this time offset to every call to time.time() even if time.time() is called by some other modules like "logging"

Comment: @DavidosKrausos Not aware of any elegant way. Probably requires some sort of monkey patching the functions you want to return modified time. Anyway, having reliable time in whole system is definitely worth to go, otherwise you will be patching on too many (and wrong) places while still having not precise time. I have seen similar attempts in my practice and I was really happy to remove those modifications from my code and rely only on what system is reporting to me.

Comment: Jan Vlcinsky i fully agree with your point here. But i'am not allowed (politics..) to change the installed ntp client. One reason this monitoring is neccessary is that the installed ntp client sometimes changes the date to the future and i need a way to get notified when this has happens.

Comment: The most elegant way is to provide a module, which gives you the desired time with your offset. There is no need to monkey patch anything, you'll run into troubles. Just figure out which of your used modules/functions need your time offset and wrap/decorate them.

Comment: @septi it seems there is no way around this. So i'll go this way then..